How can release flutter in the different option?
I create a Flutter app for my company which able to connect to a web api service to get the information, however, we decided let 2 entities (2 database in the backend) to use the app, so I need to relased 2 apps but coneect to 2 different web api address. is this feasible?
define 2 web api line in the Flutter.
can I choose one of them when I released the app? if can change the app icon would be better.
thanks

You should user flavors to archive this kinds of requirements.
https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors
